# "Could not sign in x-apple-md-action_message" when signing in to App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I was trying to download a game from the App Store on my iPhone 5c (iOS 8.4) and I put in my password to download it but I got a pop-up message on my screen saying this: "Could not sign in x-apple-md-action_message". What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when a connection cannot be established.  To fix it, try the following:

- Sign out of the App Store

  - Go to **Settings > App and iTunes Stores**
  - Tap your Apple ID and tap Sign out
- Shut down your iPhone
- Restart your iPhone
- Sign back into the App Store with your Apple ID.